# fetch a single value from return class

Tags: php

i have a function that when execute:

```
try {
            $soapClientObj = new SoapClient("http://xxx.xxx/Post/Send.asmx?wsdl");
            $parameters['username'] = "xxxx";
            $parameters['password'] = "xxx";
            $parameters['from'] = "xxx";
            $parameters['to'] = $numbers;
            $parameters['text'] = $text;
            $parameters['recId'] = array(0);
            $parameters['status'] = array(0);

            print_r($soapClientObj->SendSms($parameters));

        } catch (SoapFault $fault) {
            echo  "$fault";
        }
```

return this value

```
stdClass Object (
                [SendSmsResult] => 1 
                [recId] => stdClass Object ( 
                               [long] => 4231441553676114840 ) 
                [status] => )
```

i want to print just  `4231441553676114840` , but i dont know how to do this
help me if you can, thank you so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo $soapClientObj->SendSms($parameters)->recId->long;
```

Comment: It should be `$params->recId->long;`

Comment: Thanks, I have fixed it. I thought the object could be accessed like an array/table.

Answer (score 1):

here is how:

```
try {
            $soapClientObj = new SoapClient("http://path/to/wsdl/api/url");
            $parameters['username'] = "xxxx";
            $parameters['password'] = "xxx";
            $parameters['from'] = "xxx";
            $parameters['to'] = $numbers;
            $parameters['text'] = $text;
            $parameters['recId'] = array(0);
            $parameters['status'] = array(0);

            $response = $soapClientObj->SendSms($parameters);

            $recId = $response->recId->long; // here is your variable

        } catch (SoapFault $fault) {
            echo  "$fault";
        }
```